# What does % mean in SASS?

Tags: sass

I saw this code, when i was checking Drupal Omega 4 theme

```
%container {
    @include container;
    @include grid-background;
}
```

what does the '%container' mean?
what is the '%' for?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/placeholder-selectors

> Placeholder Selectors: %foo
>
> Sass supports a special type of selector called a “placeholder
> selector”. These look like class and id selectors, except the # or .
> is replaced by %. They’re meant to be used with the @extend directive;
> for more information see @extend-Only Selectors.
>
> On their own, without any use of @extend, rulesets that use
> placeholder selectors will not be rendered to CSS.

**Example**

SCSS SYNTAX

```css
    %toolbelt {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border-top: 1px rgba(#000, .12) solid;
      padding: 16px 0;
      width: 100%;
    
      &:hover { border: 2px rgba(#000, .5) solid; }
    }
    
    .action-buttons {
      @extend %toolbelt;
      color: #4285f4;
    }
    
    .reset-buttons {
      @extend %toolbelt;
      color: #cddc39;
    }
```

CSS Output

```css
    .action-buttons, .reset-buttons {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border-top: 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) solid;
      padding: 16px 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .action-buttons:hover, .reset-buttons:hover {
      border: 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) solid;
    }

    .action-buttons {
      color: #4285f4;
    }
    
    .reset-buttons {
      color: #cddc39;
    }
```

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? It basically this reference: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/placeholder-selectors and it doesn't even have an example input & output. I would recommend revising this answer and currently got more from the other answers.

Comment: @jasonleonhard from the [tour]: _The person who asked can mark one answer as "accepted". Accepting doesn't mean it's the best answer, it just means that it worked for the person who asked_ . Regardless of this, it does answer the question: _'%' in SASS, what does it mean_

Answer (score 19):

**SASS**

```
%icon {
  transition: background-color ease .2s;
  margin: 0 .5em;
}

.error-icon {
  @extend %icon;
  /* error specific styles... */
}

.info-icon {
  @extend %icon;
  /* info specific styles... */
}
```

**Output**

```
.error-icon, .info-icon {
  transition: background-color ease .2s;
  margin: 0 .5em;
}

.error-icon {
  /* error specific styles... */
}

.info-icon {
  /* info specific styles... */
}
```

**Note**

Placeholder selectors have the additional property that they will not show up in the generated CSS, only the selectors that extend them will be included in the output.

**More info**

http://thesassway.com/intermediate/understanding-placeholder-selectors

**Tools**

If you want to play around Sass please use - http://sassmeister.com/

Answer (score 13):

It's a placeholder selector. It doesn't do anything on its own but can be extended, like an abstract base class.

Comment: Great, simple explanation and comparison.