# How to remove pseudo selector in SCSS?

Tags: css, sass, nested, selector, extend

In SCSS, I used `@extend` for merging 2 selectors in 1 line but the pseudo selector(:before) is created inside of `#bar` like this:

```
#foo {
  position: relative;
  &:before {
    width: 200px;
  }
}
#bar {
  @extend #foo;
}
```

Output:

```
#foo, #bar {
  position: relative; 
}
#foo:before, #bar:before {
  width: 200px; 
}
```

I want to make like this by using SCSS:

```
#foo, #bar {
  position: relative; 
}
#foo:before {
  width: 200px; 
}
/* I want to remove #bar:before */
```

Is there any ways to remove unwanted pseudo selector by creating `@extend`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [`placeholder selector(%)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17251801/in-sass-what-does-it-mean) to declare your shared properties to `#foo` and `#bar`

[See example](https://jsfiddle.net/ega27tsq/)

**Use as below:**

```
%shared {
  position: relative;
}
#foo{
   @extend %shared;
    &:before {
    width: 200px;
    content:'';
  }
}
#bar {
    @extend %shared;
}
```